# onClick is firing right away

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs

I have the following reactJs component:

```
var Pagination = React.createClass({

  // Basic pagination
  render: function() {
    // Do we have more then one page?
    if (this.props.maxPages > 0){
      var pageLink = this.props.maxPages;
      var liElements = []

      for (var i = 1; i <= pageLink; i++) {
          liElements.push(<li key={i} id={i}><a href="#" onClick={this.props.handlePaginate(i)}>{i}</a></li>);
      }

      return (<ul className="pagination">{liElements}</ul>);
    }else{
      // Return nothing.
      return ( <div></div> );
    }
  }

});
```

Each of the `li` elements has a link element, and each of those has a `onClick=...` attribute. the function thats being passed in is in a backbone view and has a console.log(id) in it. When the page loads, if there are two `li`'s on the page you get the `i` variable spit out twice. This also happens if you click on one of the `li` elements.

My question is - why is the onClick firing when I load the page for x number of `li` elements and why, when I click on one `li` element does it spit out the `i` variable for each `li` element?

the `handlePaginate` function looks like

```
handlePaginate: function(id) {
  console.log(id); //=> 1,2 (for two li elements with id's of 1 and 2)
  return false; //=> doesn't actually stop the page from refreshing oO
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that the way to solve this is to do:

```
onClick = {this.props.handlePaginate.bind(this, i)}
```

in the link value, this will stop the pagination event from firing, and stop the page from refreshing when you click on a `li` element.

Comment: Right. `this.props.handlePaginate(i)` in your example is a function call on `handlePaginate`. `this.props.handlePaginate.bind()` calls [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which returns a bound function. It doesn't call `handlePaginate` immediately.